# Javascript, can't read string in format JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass my variable like this, but it doesn't work, and gives me this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

What's wrong ?

Example:

```
var arr = "\'id\':1";
alert(arr);
```

I forgot something, after that, code.
I have render my HTML in JavaScript so like this:

```
row += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-sm btn-square btn-outline-info' type='buttond' onclick='edit(\""+arr+"\")'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>";
```

I get an error after i click that.

Thanks again

Comment: That runs good in my browser. In which line does the error refer to?

Comment: If `arr` is already a string, it doesn't need quotes around it. `onclick='edit(arr)'`

Comment: Is this what you are trying then it works fine in my browser too https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WaoRWo

Comment: @Mohammed u know dude, when u klik thats href, will be give error :(

Comment: Despite my comment above, it's not clear if you intend for the `onclick` to pass `edit` the current value of `arr` globally, or the value of `arr` at the time of the element's creation.

Comment: ahhh.. i got it,thats the answers, i must create arr to variabel global.
then now its work :D thanks dude (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try `onclick='edit(arr)'`

```js
var row = '';
var arr = "\'id\':1";
row += "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-sm btn-square btn-outline-info' type='buttond' onclick='edit(arr)'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Test</a>";

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', row);
function edit(a){
  alert(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
"<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn btn-sm btn-square btn-outline-info' type='buttond' onclick='edit("+arr+")'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>"
```

> improtant => onclick='edit("+arr+")'

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = '\\\'id\\\':1';
const row = `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-square btn-outline-info" type="buttond" onclick="edit(${arr})"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>`;

console.log(row)
```